# Cannot choose the Predictive Apriori algorithm in Weka, but can choose Apriori

Tags: algorithm, weka, data-mining, prediction, apriori

everyone!
I am trying to generate some association rules that contain my target variable. 
I want to use the Predictive Apriori algorithm in the WEKA tool, however, I cannot seem to choose it (it is grey).
I can choose Apriori.

Does Predictive Apriori take a different kind of format in terms of binary/nominal values? I take it accepts all non-numeric ones.

The arff header:

```
@relation janes 
@attribute favorited_meta_binarized {0,1} 
@attribute retweeted_meta_binarized {0,1} 
@attribute standard_tech_meta=T1_binarized {0,1} 
@attribute standard_tech_meta=T2_binarized {0,1} %and so on. 
@attribute class_mf {male,female}  %this is the target variable
```

Big thanks!

Comment: Can you add a description of your data, e.g. weka header? Maybe, add also a few data points. I assume your assumption with the feature/target value class is correct.

Comment: I have a dataset of tweets: the attributes are some tweet metadata and unigrams. The target variable is the gender of Twitter users.

Comment: [at]relation janes

[at]attribute favorited_meta_binarized {0,1}
[at]attribute retweeted_meta_binarized {0,1}
[at]attribute standard_tech_meta=T1_binarized {0,1}
[at]attribute standard_tech_meta=T2_binarized {0,1}       %and so on. The [at] is of course the @ sign, but I had to replace it here. @CAFEBABE

Comment: Added the comments via edit to your question is it make the question more self contained. And the target is also binarized?

Comment: Do you have a class attribute to *predict*?

Comment: @CAFEBABE Thank you, that was very useful.   Well, the target variable is the gender, which has 2 values (male/female). I presume that this makes it binary. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes it makes it binary. I guess it is something from the "and so on". Most likely your intended target var. I generated a sample file for the header which is now in the question and there it works like a charm (WEKA 3.6). Maybe just keep these four attributes and your target to make a test file. If that works add attribute by attribute.

Comment: Thanks, that great news. In the question, I added the line with the target variable. Your suggestion sound great, accept that I have lots of attributes (over 100,000), most of them are unigrams, e.g. words appearing in tweets. Only the first few are binarized metadata.  Do you perhaps have any other idea how to deal with this?

Comment: @code_505 Best would be to add one example of each feature type,e.g. if it works for one binarized var it is most likely working for all. My testfile works also for the current version. Can you upload the header together with a few lines  of data to a data hoster, e.g., drop box